# Why if a read a float and I printf it as an int it shows a random value? (c)

Tags: c

If I have float a = 12.767; and I printf("%d",a); Why it does not printf 13 as I am printing aa float as an int?

Comment: Basically because `printf` isn't smart enough to do that.

Comment: You need to do `printf("%d",(int)a);`. But this truncates, it does not round.

Comment: When you pass numbers to `printf`, with one or two exceptions, no automatic conversions happen.  Definitely no conversions happen due to mismatches between the type you pass, and the type expected by the `%`-specifier you use.  These days, integers and floating-point values can get passed using completely different mechanisms.  So when you pass a `float`, but tell printf (via `%d`) to expect an `int`, what `printf` actually gets when it goes to fetch an `int` may be basically a random value, unrelated to the `float` value you passed.

Comment: Or you could `printf("%.0f", a);`

Comment: So basically if printf ("%d", a) expects an int and a is a float, it will printf a random number because that is not an int. So this is like apples with apples and banas with bananas. I mean if I want to printf a float the value must be a float and if I want to printf an int, the value must be an int. Otherwise it will take a random value. Is correct what I have said?

Comment: @rayo7 That is basically correct.  You can pass `float` when printf expects `double` (that is, for `%f` and `%g`).  You can pass `char` or `short int` when printf expects `int` (that is, for `%d` and `%c`).  You can pass `unsigned char` or `unsigned short int` when printf expects `unsigned int` (that is, for `%o` and `%x`). Otherwise, the types should match exactly.  (The actual rules are a little more complicated than this, especially when it comes to the nuances of `unsigned`.  In particular, what I said about `char` and `%d` was slightly wrong, and someone's about to correct me.)

Comment: Question 1- Why if int a= 13 and I printf ("%f", a) it shows always 0.0000 (it does not matter the value of the int it also shows 0.000 if a=27) and it does not show a random number as in b=13.78 printf ("%d, b) ithat shows a random number?

Comment: @rayo7: Undefined behavior is *undefined* -- there's no telling what will happen.

Comment: Question 2- Why if I define double a = 56.76; and I printf("%f", a) it does not show a random value, (it shoud be %lf because it is a double type not a float type.

Comment: @rayo7: Both `%f` and `%lf` [expect a `double` argument](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf). A `float` argument is converted to `double` when passed to `printf`.

Comment: But why if float a = 32.89; and I printf("%lf", a); the output is 32.889999 and if double a = 32.89; and I printf ("%f", a) ; the output here is 32.890000. Why the outputs are differents if printf transform float to double if it is %lf and double to float if it is %f?

Comment: Re "*When you pass numbers to printf, with one or two exceptions, no automatic conversions happen.*", Those are: Standard integer promotions (`char`, `signed char`, `unsigned char`, `signed short`, `unsigned short`  become `signed int` or `unsigned int`) and, `float` is converted to `double`.

Comment: @ikegami so why if I pass a float 32.8900 to printf and i use %lf as well as you said it is an exception and the float is converted to double so 32.8900 was a float and now is a double, but the value now is 32.89999. Why the value has changed? I don't understand it

Comment: Re "*so why if I pass a float 32.8900 to printf and i use %lf as well as you said it is an exception*", That's not true. C doesn't even have exceptions, for starters. And it's not an error or warning either. In fact, `%lf` was only introduced to `*printf` in C99, and it means the same as `%f`.

Comment: Re "*Why the value has changed?*", The value didn't change. Your had the `float` 32.8899993896484375, and that didn't change when it was upgraded to a `double`  when passed to `printf`.

Comment: Keep in mind that 89/100 is a periodic number in binary just like 1/3 in decimal. It can't be represented exactly by a floating pointer number (`float` or `double`). Truncating the periodic number at different points (`float` vs `double`) results in different numbers. With a IEEE double-precision number (a `double` on a x68/x64), is the closest number to 32.89 to 32.8900000000000005684341886080801486968994140625. With as single-precision (`float` on a x68/x64), 32.8899993896484375.

Comment: [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/944YMhqcv)

Comment: @rayo7 Curious, Who or what text suggest  `float` type and not `double a = 12.767;`?

Comment: @ikegami Re: Those are: Standard integer promotions (char, signed char, unsigned char, signed short, unsigned short become signed int or unsigned int) and, float is converted to double. What do you mean "those are". I thought you were referring to the exceptions as the other user said "with one or two expceptions" and you awnsered, those are.. What were you referring then?

Comment: Those are the implicit type conversion performed on arguments provided to `*printf`. So yes, those are the exceptions to "no automatic conversions happen" Steve Summit mentioned. You provide a `char`, it will get promoted to an `signed int` or `unsigned int`. You provide a `float`, it will get promoted to a `double`.

Comment: @ikegami so you said that float is an exception and is converted to double in printf and later I said "so why if I pass a float 32.8900 to printf and i use %lf as well as you said it is an exception and the float is converted to double "  and you awnsered "That's not true. C doesn't even have exceptions, for starters.". I don't understand then, you said that a float is an exception and in printf if there is %lf it is converted to double...

Comment: Sorry, I thought you meant it threw an exception. Re "*so why if I pass a float 32.8900 to printf and i use %lf as well as you said it is an exception*", Cause it's one of the cases where C does perform an automatic conversion. To a `double`, to be specific.

Comment: @ikegami and what is the difference between trowing an exception and being an expeption? I don't know what does it mean to throw an exception

Comment: It doesn't exist in C, so not relevant here.

Comment: @ikegami so basically my conclusion is that double type and float type have different precisions methods so for this reason reading a float number and a double number it does not matter that the number is the same because the output will be different due to the different precisions of double and float.Am I wrong?